# Library not loaded exception

Tags: ios, exception, cocoapods, ios9, xcode7-beta2

I have been developing my application targeting iOS 9 for the last month or so using the simulator only. The project compiles and runs on the simulator without any issues.

Today I upgraded my phone to iOS 9 Beta 2 and deployed the app to it for the first time. Upon startup the application crashes with the following output in the console.

> dyld: Library not loaded: @rpath/Pods_LifeStream.framework/Pods_LifeStream
>     Referenced from: /var/mobile/Containers/Bundle/Application/A2289417-624C-49E0-A932-AEC89CA1DEF3/LifeStream.app/LifeStream
>     Reason: image not found

I'm assuming this is due to one of the frameworks i'm using needing an image that it can't find. Is there a way for me to determine which pod is causing the issue, and why it runs on the simulator but not on my device?

Comment: I think the framework you are talking about is Lifestream and you installed it as a Pod.  Check all the images you have on that project and check if all the image files are uploaded to your device.

Comment: Actually the Lifestream is my project. It's not broken out in to a framework or anything. I just created a new project, called it Lifestream, added some cocoapods to it and started developing. Should there be images on a default iOS project?

Comment: They should be there but maybe some of them are not there.  Another thing you can do is put some breakpoints in your code to check when the exception is raised or uninstall all the cocoapods and start to install one by one to see what is the pod that have the problem.  That is the way I would try yo find the missing image.  I have an additional question, if you run your project in the simulator you receive the exception as well?

Comment: If I run the project in the simulator, it starts up with zero exceptions. When running on-device, my break points in `application: didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:` doesn't even get hit before the exception occurs. I'll try removing some pods; that's difficult because the app depends on them to compile.

Comment: What if you clean (Command+Shift+K) your project in the simulator and the device before the build it (Command+Shift+B)? Do you receive the same result or something changes?

Comment: Yeah, I had tried that as well. Same result

Comment: Another thing you can do is to compare the package installed in your phone vs your package running in the simulator.  To get the package in you phone you can use IExplorer, after that you can see if there is any missing image in the phone.  My suspect is that maybe you have an image in your project that is not added to your target.